# Detect screen mirroring on chromecast

Tags: android, broadcast, chromecast, mirroring

Is it possible to detect if screen mirroring to a chromecast stick is active? Is there a system broadcast or something else?

Comment: Yes, you can. Take a look at the sample app: https://github.com/googlecast/CastPresentation-android

Comment: @LeonNicholls: That sample *does* mirroring. I fail to see what in that sample *detects* if *somebody else* is doing mirroring, which is my interpretation of the question. If there's code in that sample that detects mirroring, could you indicate where specifically we can find it? Thanks!

Comment: CommonsWare interpretation of my question is right. I would like to know if a connection already exists, especially if the connection has not been initiated through my app (like screen mirroring on the nexus 5). Is this something, we could detect by the NDK?

Comment: The sample doesn't do mirroring. It detects when the user has enabled mirroring and then uses the projection API to render a secondary display.

Comment: @Leon: Sorry you are right. Your sample does correctly detect the mirroring. Would you like to post your answer, so i can mark this thread as resolved? (at)commonsware: take a look at line 155-157

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @LeonNicholls Could you find the link again or post the answer? The original no longer works.